# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid React-Native

Tags: react-native

When I try to make reusable components in my code but it shows some error.

[image]

Below are my codes

Login.js

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={login.container}>
      <Image source={imageLogo} style={login.logo} />
      <View style={login.form}>
        <ApptiTextInput
          value={this.state.email}
          onChangeText={this.handleEmailChange}
          placeholder={strings.EMAIL_PLACEHOLDER}
        />
        <ApptiTextInput
          value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={this.handlePasswordChange}
          placeholder={strings.PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER}
        />
        <ApptiButton label={strings.LOGIN} handleLoginPress={this.handleLoginPress.bind(this)} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Apptibutton.js

```
render() {
    const { label, handleLoginPress } = this.props;
    console.log(label);

    return (
      <View  style={apptiButton.container}>
         <TouchableOptacity onPress={handleLoginPress}>
            <Text style={apptiButton.text} >{label}</Text>
         </TouchableOptacity>
      </View>

    );
}
```

[Here is my code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u84wwiP98fx8_arN7m7gWzA1lKsSlU4C/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: could you please send the whole code

Comment: I added my code as drive link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in `Apptibutton.js`, `TouchableOpacity` instead of `TouchableOptacity`:

```
render() {
    const { label, handleLoginPress } = this.props;
    console.log(label);

    return (
      <View  style={apptiButton.container}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLoginPress}>
            <Text style={apptiButton.text} >{label}</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    );
}
```